# ionic: Starter app with -v1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting started with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/getting-started/). I want to use ionic 1. I am using following command to create ionic v1 app as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs//intro/installation/).

`ionic start -v1 myapp blank`

But it's creating ionic v2 app using angular 2. I don't know why it is doing so. I also tried commands below but no luck.

`ionic -v1 start myapp blank`

`ionic start myapp -v1 blank`

`ionic start myapp blank -v1`

It's not showing any error or warning either. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: try without `-v1 ` if this doesn't help maybe try to downgrade the ionic-cli version installed

Comment: Initially I tried without v1 but it didn't help. Let me down grade it and check.

Comment: It worked for me with v2.2.1

Comment: which is your cli version? Also you have a typo..it is `--v1`

Comment: I have tried `--v1 ` as well. It doesn't work. Anyways I will try to down grade as naomi suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade your ionic version. Then run "ionic start myproject blank" without --v

Answer (score 0):

The current way of doing this is using the `--type=ionic1` option:

```
ionic --version  # 3.8.1
ionic start test blank --type=ionic1
```